# HikariPool-2 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jhipster

I use jhipster with spring boot 2.0.6 and postgres 10

I make a stress test for my application using 1000 connexion in same time ( 1000 request).

but when running the test I have this error :

```
ERROR 28885 --- [o-8080-exec-285] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : HikariPool-2 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
WARN 28885 --- [o-8080-exec-274] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
```

I have this configuration in **application.yml**

```
jhipster:
    async:
        core-pool-size: 2
        max-pool-size: 50
        queue-capacity: 10000
```

also I have this configuration in **application-prod.yml**

```
logging:
    level:
        ROOT: INFO
        com.dq.taysir: INFO
        io.github.jhipster: INFO

spring:
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: false
        livereload:
            enabled: false
    datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: jdbc:postgresql://10.100.100.160:5432/myDatabase
        username: postgres
        password: postgres
        hikari:
            auto-commit: false
    jpa:
        database-platform: io.github.jhipster.domain.util.FixedPostgreSQL82Dialect
        database: POSTGRESQL
        show-sql: false
        properties:
            hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
            hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: false
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: io.github.jhipster.config.jcache.BeanClassLoaderAwareJCacheRegionFactory
    liquibase:
        contexts: prod
    mail:
        host: localhost
        port: 25
        username:
        password:
    thymeleaf:
        cache: true
    servlet:
       multipart:
        enabled: true
        max-file-size: 80MB
        max-request-size: 80MB


server:
    port: 8080
    compression:
        enabled: true
        mime-types: text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css, application/javascript, application/json
        min-response-size: 1024


jhipster:
    http:
        version: V_1_1 # To use HTTP/2 you will need SSL support (see above the "server.ssl" configuration)
        cache: # Used by the CachingHttpHeadersFilter
            timeToLiveInDays: 1461
    cache: # Cache configuration
        ehcache: # Ehcache configuration
            time-to-live-seconds: 3600 # By default objects stay 1 hour in the cache
            max-entries: 1000 # Number of objects in each cache entry
    security:
        authentication:
            jwt:               
                base64-secret: ZTA4ODBmMDU4NmE0MDI3Z.................=
                # Token is valid 24 hours
                token-validity-in-seconds: 86400
                token-validity-in-seconds-for-remember-me: 2592000
    mail: # specific JHipster mail property, for standard properties see MailProperties
        from: MyApp@localhost
        base-url: http://my-server-url-to-change # Modify according to your server's URL
    metrics: # DropWizard Metrics configuration, used by MetricsConfiguration
        jmx:
            enabled: true
        prometheus:
            enabled: false #expose metrics via prometheus
        logs: # Reports Dropwizard metrics in the logs
            enabled: false
            report-frequency: 60 # in seconds
    logging:
        logstash: # Forward logs to logstash over a socket, used by LoggingConfiguration
            enabled: false
            host: localhost
            port: 5000
            queue-size: 512
```

also in **postgresql.conf** I have this configuration

```
max_connections = 1000
```

after search I find that the solution is to increase max-pool-size.

I try to make this value 1000 :

```
jhipster:
    async:
        core-pool-size: 2
        max-pool-size: 1000
        queue-capacity: 10000
```

but when running again the test I have the same error

```
HikariPool-2 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
```

How deal with this problem?

Comment: When you make a stress test, it's to find your system's limits and tune configuration for a specific hardware. Here only you know what is your hardware architecture, are you running on your PC both app, db and test? How many cores/memory? Have you tuned postgres for your hardware? Setting max_connections = 1000 in pg could be counter productive. What kind of transactions are you running in your test? You have enabled metrics (pool, cpu, memory, ..), you should use them to see how system behaves by increasing progressively number of connections.

Comment: Shouldn't the hikari pool configured via default spring boot parameters (spring.datasource.hikari.xyz)?